# Why don't SpaceIL's Beresheet spacecraft and Moon orbits line up?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, lander, lunar-orbit, beresheet, spaceil

The question [Tracking SpaceIL Beresheet Moon lander](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34539/12102) links to some data files that are from the site: http://live.spaceil.com (also linked [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34540/12102)):

> Raw data:
>
> http://live.spaceil.com/data/data_s1.txt (22/2 - 12/4)
>
> http://live.spaceil.com/data/data_s2.txt (4/4 - 12/4)
>
> http://live.spaceil.com/data/data_m.txt  (22/2 - 16/12)

Here's the plot of the data in `data_s1.txt` (spacecraft) and `data_m.txt` (Moon). There are proper state vectors for the spacecraft $[x, y, z, v_x, v_y, v_z]$ but only position vectors for the Moon. $[x, y, z]$.

There is a real problem though; they don't align correctly! The spacecraft does not orbit the Moon. Not even close!

I think there may be something screwy with the data. the error is much bigger than 1/81 so it's more than just barycenter versus Earth-center coordinates. Something's wrong.

**Question:** Why don't SpaceIL's spacecraft and moon orbits line up?

[image]

[image]

Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

with open('data_s1.txt', 'r') as infile:
    slines   = infile.readlines()

slines   = [ [float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')[1:]] for line in slines[1:-1]]
sstates  = np.array(zip(*slines))

with open('data_m.txt', 'r') as infile:
    mlines   = infile.readlines()

mlines   = [ [float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')[1:]] for line in mlines[1:-1]]
mstates  = np.array(zip(*mlines))

if True:    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])  # [12, 10]

    ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
    x, y, z = sstates[:3]
    ax.plot(x, y, z, '-r')

    x, y, z = mstates[:3]
    ax.plot(x, y, z, '-b')

    ax.set_xlim(-405000, 405000)
    ax.set_ylim(-405000, 405000)
    ax.set_zlim(-405000, 405000)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: From what I’ve read Beresheet has a very low-thrust engine, and has to make multiple burns through April to extend its apoapsis out to lunar orbit. Maybe that accounts for your confusion?

Comment: @Snoopy I've added an additional image to clarify the gross mismatch.

Comment: have you tried plotting in in a moon centred frame?

Comment: Frighteningly, if you plot one orbit with minus signs in front of x, y, and z it matches almost perfectly at first glance.

Comment: What do your plots show?

Comment: @Hobbes The blue circles come from `data_m` and are presumably meant to be the Moon, and the red ellipses that start following the Moon come from `data_s1` and are presumably the spacecraft. I don't know what else to explain beyond what I wrote in the question. If there's something specific I can explain better, let me know.

Comment: What are the X, Y and Z axes of your plot, and what do the red and blue lines represent? Positions in km, blue = moon, red = Beresheet?

Comment: @Hobbes I have explained in the text that these are plots of data files from a website. That's all I know about them. They come with no explanation. All those seem like reasonable guesses, and looking at the agreement with Horizons to a few kilometers shown in my answer below, it's almost certainly correct.

Comment: @Hobbes My question was about making sense of these files, and my answer shows what I've figured out. It all seems to make sense now. A bit of "orbital detective work" I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Moon is upside down!!

First line of `data_m.txt`:

```
22 Feb 2019 00:25:25.342,360092.027359,47067.127093,-13285.073162
```

JPL Horizons for position of Luna relative to the Geocenter using ICRF ("Earth Mean Equator and Equinox of Reference Epoch"):

```
2458536.518055555, A.D. 2019-Feb-22 00:26:00.0000, -3.600940899651895E+05, -4.703362154841860E+04,  1.329822258680163E+04,
```

[image]

Shown together in same format:

```
source         date          time          x            y           z
data_m     22 Feb 2019   00:25:25.342   360,092.0    47,067.1   -13,285.1
Horizons   2019-Feb-22   00:26:00.000  -360,094.1   -47,033.6    13,298.2
```

Differences of seconds and tens of kilometers may be buried in leap seconds and different ephemerides ([pronunciation guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370655/217285)), basically SpaceIL's Moon's orbit is *Upside Down!*

Another way to look at it is that `data_s1.txt` is the position of the spacecraft wrt geocenter, but `data_m.txt` is the position of the Earth relative to the **lunacenter**.

I always wanted to use "lunacenter" in an answer.

The two files use different time spacings, and I'm not going to interpolate one to the other just to make a plot. Instead I can plot x, y, z separately as a function of time in seconds since the earliest time that appears in one of the files.

$x, y, z$ plotted with minus signs in front of the coordinates only in the `data_m.txt` file:

[image]